# WPF Animation to all rectangles in a grid

Tags: wpf

I am a starter in wpf programming. The following code shows an error when I tried to animate colour of all rectangles used in grid 2. Do you know why?

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid2"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Rectangle.Fill.Color"
                To="Indigo"/>
```

Comment: Grids do not have a `Rectangle.Fill.Color` property. Or more generally, animations animate a single property on a single element. You may however animate the color of one Rectangle, and bind the Fill property of the others to the Fill of the animated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AniamateRectangle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" BeginTime="0:0:0.2" Duration="0:0:0.5"  To="Indigo"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Style="{StaticResource AniamateRectangle}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="Transparent" Width="100"/>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="Transparent" Width="100" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="Transparent" Width="100" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```